# Cannot run latest version of xamarin on MAC having OS 10.7.5

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I have Mac Mini with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 and i was trying to install the latest version of xamarin studio on Mac as i have a windows machine (Having latest xamarin studio installed) and want to connect it to Mac for developing IOS app.

But i cannot run latest version of xamarin on my mac machine, can anyone tell me how can i create a ios app on 10.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

What are the minimum system requirements?

Xamarin requires the platform SDKs from Apple and Google to target iOS or Android, and **our system requirements match theirs**. To build for iOS, you'll need the latest iOS SDK (currently iOS 8.1), which ships with Xcode 6.1 and requires **Mac OSX 10.9.4+ (Mavericks) or 10.10 (Yosemite)**. Our Visual Studio Extensions for iOS and Android support any non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

http://xamarin.com/faq